# Full outer join SQL error jj

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider:

```
Select Dash_Bill_ID As 'رقم الفاتورة',
       c2.Customer_Name As 'العميل',
       c1.Customer_Name As 'المهندس/المقاول',
       delegate.Delegate_Name As 'المندوب',
       Total_CostBD As 'الاجمالي قبل الخصم',
       Total_CostAD As 'الاجمالي بعد الخصم',
       Bill_Date As 'التاريخ',
       Type_Buy As 'طريقة الدفع',
       Initial_Value As 'العربون',
       bank.Bank_Name As 'الخزنة'
From   customer_bill
Full Outer Join customer As c1
    On c1.Customer_ID = customer_bill.Customer_ID
Full Outer Join customer As c2
    On c2.Customer_ID = customer_bill.Client_ID
Full Outer Join delegate
    On delegate.Delegate_ID = customer_bill.Delegate_ID
Full Outer Join bank
    On bank.Bank_ID = customer_bill.Bank_ID
Where  Dash_Bill_ID = 24;
```

I get an error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer join customer as c1 on c1.Customer_ID=customer_bill.Customer_ID full outer' at line 1

Comment: MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: There is no `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN` which is the specific problem you are experiencing.

However, it is highly unlikely that a `FULL JOIN` is even desired.  In a well-constructed databases, full joins are almost never needed.  Assuming that all referenced fields are non-`NULL` in `customer_bill`, the `INNER JOIN` should be fine.  Alternatively, you might want a `LEFT JOIN`.